# How designer-friendly is PlayN and are there libraries I should know about to be more designer friendly?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, playn

I'm on a small tactics game development team where we only have one programmer, and I am attempting to assist in programming. We are both learning PlayN (indie team) and I'm wondering if there are any visual or data driven tools, or libraries that can assist with a more data (HTML/XML/Spreadsheet) driven approach for major components (menu system, story/cutscene system (might also be used for unit encyclopedia and win/loss screens), the main game (tiles/units/UI/inventory)) so that we can have a rapid/iterative dev cycle.

Is PlayN the best engine for a multiplatform (key platform Android) game for devs getting into Android/mobile development or should we look at a different engine?

I have been doing my research - I already know a little bit about SimpleTMX and TriplePlay, but on the lookout for more tools to speed up development.

Comment: I have noticed that a lot of playn questions go unanswered on stackoverflow for now. So if you want a quick reply, you can post this question's link on their mailing list. That might help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Google PlayN does not have any editor or something else. The first step would be to even write a level loader. I don't have any ideas wheater PlayN can load files like XML. It's just a library for code.

For creating 2d multiplatform games you should take a look at Gamemaker Studio. Just google it. It has lots of things like collisions and physics built in bit it's expensive. For 3d games you could take a look at Unreal Engine, Unity, Delta Engine or Cryengine but they're also very expensive.

Comment: For PlayN, as for most modern Javascript and Mobile development, you would use JSON over XML. A JSON parser is included in PlayN.